# How create substring when i know first and last characters in the string with C#?

Tags: c#, string, substring

I am new in C# please help to write in efficient C# way.

The case(always first character is '-'  and the last is '>'):

Example 1:

```
input:   bdfdfd-wr>
output:  wr
```

Example 2:

```
input:   -dsdsds-sdsds-grtt>
output:  grtt
```

Example 3:

```
input:   -dsdsds-sdsds-grtt>><>>dfdfdfd
output:  grtt
```

Example 4:

```
input:   -dsdsds-sdsds-grtt>><->>df-d=fdfd
output:  grtt
```

Comment: What if you have multiple `>` characters?

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     string input = "-dsdsds-sdsds-grtt>";
     int startInd = input.LastIndexOf('-');
     int endInd = input.IndexOf('>', startInd);
     string result;
     if (startInd < endInd) 
         result = input.Substring(startInd + 1, endInd - startInd - 1);
```

EDIT:

```
    string input = "-dsdsds-sdsds-grtt>><->>df-d=fdfd";
    string str = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf('>'));
    string result = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('-') + 1);
```

Using linq seems to be also a good option:

```
var result = input.Split('>').First().Split('-').Last();
```

Comment: thanks,but last char should be ">" and not "-", please see example 4 that i add

Answer (score 2):

```
string example = "-dsdsds-sdsds-grtt>";
int lastIndexOfHyphen = example.LastIndexOf("-");
int indexOfBracket = example.IndexOf(">", lastIndexOfHyphen);
string substr = example.Substring(lastIndexOfHyphen + 1, indexOfBracket - lastIndexOfHyphen - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, although I do see a flaw--if a hyphen appears after the angled bracket, this will fail.

Comment: yeah may be, but IMO, important thing was to tell the OP about the use `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf` method

Comment: thanks,but last char should be ">" and not "-", please see example 4 that i add

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways:

- Use a [regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx), something like `-([a-z]+)>`. The result would then be in [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx)`.Groups[1]`.
- Use [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) to find the `>`, use [LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof) to find the last dash, and then use [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring) to get the word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).

---

**Example:**

```
var r = new Regex(@"-(\w*)>");

var inputs = new [] { "bdfdfd-wr>",
                      "-dsdsds-sdsds-grtt>",
                      "-dsdsds-sdsds-grtt>><>>dfdfdfd",
                      "-dsdsds-sdsds-grtt>><->>df-d=fdfd" };

foreach(var i in inputs)
    Console.WriteLine(r.Match(i).Groups[1].Value);
```

**Output:**

> wr
>   grtt
>   grtt
>   grtt

Answer (score 1):

```
        string s = "-dsdsds-sdsds-grtt>";
        string output = null;
        if (s.Contains(">"))
        {
            output = s.Split(new string[] { ">" }, 
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                      .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Contains("-"));
            if (output != null)
                output = output.Substring(output.LastIndexOf("-") + 1);
        }
```

Returns the first-in-line text wrapped into - and >. If input is `"-dsdsds-sdsds-grtt>asdas-asq>"`, it will return `grtt`; for `-dsdsds-sdsds-grtt>><>>dfdfdfd` - returns `grtt` as well

[There](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) you can find a great deal of methods to work with strings.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ style:

```
var output = input.Split('>').First().Split('-').Last();
```